# Differentiation and integration of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, derivatives, definite-integrals, power-series

If I have a  power series $$\sum _{k}^{\infty }f(x)$$ and I differentiate it I get according to my current knowledge $\sum _{k}^{\infty }f(x)'$,however when I look at a power series defined by $$\sum _{0}^{\infty }a_{n}\left( x-c\right) ^{n}$$ When one takes the derivative you get$$\sum _{1}^{\infty }n\cdot a_{n}\left( x-c\right) ^{n-1}$$Why is this the case? Does this hold for general series? Did I miss something obvious? When taking derivative at specific point does one just plug in the value of x in $f(x)'$ inside the $\sum $? Does such a operation even exist? Does the derivative operation when applied to a series have a physical interpretation in the real world? Does the definite for series follow from this definition? I sincerely apologize if I asked to many questions.

Comment: I'm not sure I see the problem. The derivative of $(x-c)^n$ is $n\cdot (x-c)^{n-1}$, and the series starts at $n=1$ because the $n=0$ term is zero.

Comment: Doh that was a stupid mistake. I have looked at it term by term and I can now see my folly.

Comment: @semiclassical turn that into an answer and close this off :)). Good job!